# Setting WordPress option values as constants

Tags: php, wordpress

Pretty straightforward, would the below code have any issues with security or performance? I believe constants are slightly faster than using variables but I am sure the benefit would be negligible:

```
$payment    = get_option('swd_billing_payment');
define('SWD_OWNER_CURRENCY', isset($payment['swd_owner_currency']) ? $payment['swd_owner_currency'] : '');
define('SWD_OWNER_CURRENCY_SYMBOL', isset($payment['swd_owner_currency_symbol']) ? $payment['swd_owner_currency_symbol'] : '');
define('SWD_OWNER_BANK', isset($payment['swd_owner_bank']) ? $payment['swd_owner_bank'] : '');
define('SWD_OWNER_ACCOUNT_NAME', isset($payment['swd_owner_account_name']) ? $payment['swd_owner_account_name'] : '');
```

There would end up being around 30 constants defined for the various settings in the database.

Comment: Not really a good SO question, but yes i dont see a problem with that. I would suggest setting a usable default though, an empty string is not much use

Comment: You should change your question quickly before it's closed as eg "too broad". Using the term "bad practice" opens your question up for personal opinion, which is not welcomed here really. You need to restructure your question so it can be answered cleanly. i.e. "Would doing this cause security issues". "Too much overhead", "Conflicts somewhere" etc

Comment: Thanks @Steve fair point.

Comment: @James, thanks I have changed the question slightly.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about a few +- micro seconds difference with Wordpress, it's notoriously slow and improvements are usually measured in seconds or half seconds (caching helps greatly of course). (I don't know enough about WP Core to comment on security concerns when introducing user Constants.)